# Does UTF-8 have more than one version?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, unicode-normalization

I read the following in [PHP Manual > Language Reference > Types: Details of the String Type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details):

> Given that PHP does not dictate a specific encoding for strings, one
> might wonder how string literals are encoded. For instance, is the
> string "`á`" equivalent to "`\xE1`" (ISO-8859-1), "`\xC3\xA1`" (UTF-8, C
> form), "`\x61\xCC\x81`" (UTF-8, D form) or any other possible
> representation?

What does "*UTF-8, C form*" and "*UTF-8, D form*" mean - are they two versions of UTF-8?

Comment: There's only one UTF-8, but it provides multiple ways to encode the same character.

Comment: @Barmar It's not UTF-8 that provides multiple ways, but the Unicode standard.  `á` can be a composed of a single Unicode codepoint (U+00E1) or two code points (U+0061 U+0301, decomposed form).

Comment: @MarkTolonen How does that relate to the C form and D form in the quoted text?

Comment: @barmar Unicode Normalization form C (composed) and Unicode Normalization form D (decomposed). The first started with one composed codepoint and *then* it was encoded in UTF-8. The second started with two code points (`a` and a combining accent)

Comment: [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 C form and UTF-8 D form are two alternate ways of encoding the same Unicode code points in UTF-8, with C form using a single code unit for characters that can be represented in ASCII, and D form using two code units for all characters. Example:

- (é) in UTF-8 C is represented as two bytes: 0xC3 and 0xA9
- (é) UTF-8 D is represented as a single code point: 0xE9

Comment: One could point out that trying to match strings is great fun then: searching for `\xC3\xA1` won't find `\x61\xCC\x81` and vice versa. That's why text is [normalized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php), so it always has one of many forms.